# Not getting redirected back to website after twitter authentication

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement login using twitter and using http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth plugin for that.

Issue is after going to twitter authentication page its not redirecting back to main website.

My Callback URL is same as URL below.

Code is at : http://testenv.pagalhost.com/tw/connect.php

Any pointers as what could be the possible issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your call back your goes to http://testenv.pagalhost.com/tw/twitteroauth/callback.php
Which takes user to a 404.

Kindly post your code here so that it will be easy to nail the issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing that 404 error, created that file now but its the same issue and I am using same code as it is at https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth , just added my keys.

Comment: Issue with this problem was permission had for twitter access. 
Previously it was marked as Read Only and Later I changed it to Read and Write and because of which it was failing.